# Nfse paulistana - XML não compatível com Schema

Tags: webserver

Estou implementando o envio de NFSe porem estou recebendo o erro:

```
XML não compatível com Schema.The 'http://www.prefeitura.sp.gov.br/nfe:PedidoEnvioRPS' element is not declared.
```

Segue o XML:

[Arquivo XML](http://painel.g2rservicos.com.br/testes/teste.xml)

Comment: Poderia colocar seu código, por favor?

Comment: está faltando o namespace `http://www.prefeitura.sp.gov.br/nfe`

Comment: @RovannLinhalis atualizei o arquivo e exite o endereço citado.

Comment: alguém já passou por esse problema?